# Simple XMLHttpRequest and print XML data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to send some xml data to a server and then print on screen the xml I received.

What I have so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function authIHC() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xml_request;
var username = "user";
var password = "password";

xml_request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<ns1:authenticate1 xmlns:ns1=\"utcs\" xsi:type=\"ns1:WSAuthenticationData\">\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<ns1:password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + password + "</ns1:password>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<ns1:username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + username + "</ns1:username>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "<ns1:application xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">treeview</ns1:application>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "</ns1:authenticate1>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n";
xml_request = xml_request + "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n";

req.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (req.readyState==4)
    {
    alert(req.statusText);
    }
    else {alert ("nothing");}
  }

req.open('PUT', 'https://10.0.0.254/ws/AuthenticationService', true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
req.send(xml_request);

}
</script>
```

The problem is that I never get anything and it always print in a box: nothing.

Could you please help?

Comment: Have you looked at the response with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: Will try fiddler but is my code correct or not? can I post like this?

Comment: I have tried fiddler and even though I changed PUT to POST (sorry, that was a mistype), in fiddler I see OPTIONS instead of POST that is being sent.

Comment: Are you posting to a different ip than what you are currently on? If so you have Same Origin Policy problems.

Comment: Yes, I am posting on a different IP than my server. Is there a specific parameter to enter in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Posting to a different server means you are hitting the same origin policy. Look at the http response code and you will see it is not 400.

If you control the other domain, you can look at enabling [CORs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Only modern browsers support it.